# How does Typescript load typings? (and what each TS-related file's purpose is)

Tags: typescript

I am becoming familiar with Typescript and typings but it is not yet very clear **how to tell Typescript where to find typings** (or better... how to tell Typescript where to find them without unnecessary code).

In fact, I see several files:

- **typings.json** (apparently here it saves where to fetch the typings)
- tsconfig.json's **filesGlob** (apparently this lists all .ts files + typings)
- typings/**main.d.ts** ("root of typings", i.e. where we specify Is this actually necessary when typings are specified in filesGlob? Also, what's the difference between adding the **reference paths** here instead of individual .ts files across the app**?
- In SystemJS and CommonJS' import, can we say that every time we use the **import** function we're actually importing some module **and not just its typings**?

**What's the purpose of each of this files and which ones are actually needed?** (specifically see the questions and notes aside each file)

Comment: SO is geared towards aiding people with specific problems not generic advice/documentation. You can find all of that in the handbook here http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html or in @basarat's book here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Typescript where to find typings

Its all about the compilation context. ([more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/compilation-context.html)). If a file makes it into the context then it is analyzed.

## Ways a file can make it in

- Its in the `files`
- Its in the `filesGlob` and you are using something that understands filesGlob (e.g. atom-typescript, alm, grunt-ts)
- Its referenced (i.e. `<reference path=`) by a file that already made it into the compilation context
- Its *imported* (i.e. `import foo = require('./foo')` etc) but a file that already made it into the compilation context.
- You passed it in on the command line.
- It is a `lib` file (e.g. [`lib.d.ts`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html))

Etc.

Additionally file might be *global* or a *module* ([more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html)).

Comment: thanks for the detail answer. Would you be able to say which of the points you outlines are actually necessary in a module based application (i.e. which needs imports to work, e.g. Angular 2, React, Meteor 1.3.). So that would be import... (4th point) and what else? For example I'd prefer to put as much as possible in tsconfig