# In TypeSctipt 2.0, do you still need to include /// reference path="

Tags: typescript

In TypeSctipt 2.0, do you still need to include /// reference path=""
as in

`///<reference path="../../../../typings/app.d.ts"/>`

or is that a thing of the past as now TS searches all directories specified in tsconfig? would great if someone can elaborate with detailed answer...

tx

Sean

Answer (score 2):

You would let `tsconfig.json` specify the main files in your project (hence called *included files*. However if you have any `reference` tags in *included files* pointing to files that aren't *included*, they will get included in the compilation context as well.

I don't use `reference` comments generally.

## More

Also covered here [How does Typescript load typings? (and what each TS-related file's purpose is)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099577/how-does-typescript-load-typings-and-what-each-ts-related-files-purpose-is/37106180#37106180)